# Vraptor 4 + Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-transactions, vraptor

i'm trying to use spring modules on VRaptor, but it just don't work.

I'm using the VRaptor 4 and trying to use Spring Transaction Manager, but i can't make VRaptor use Spring as the IoC, the Autowired don't work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because VRaptor 4 is built on top of CDI. If you need to use Spring as IoC container, you still can use VRaptor 3.5.x versions.